# What is the easiest way to make a backup in visual studio 2013?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, backup

I want to make a backup from the whole project. I also need to rename every backup. I'dont like the way to copy the project folder and rename the folder and the project file.
I've already tried to make it like that:
http://jasonfaulkner.com/VisualStudioExpressProjectBuildBackups.aspx

But it doesn't work, I am always getting the error "Invalid parameters"

Does anyone already tried this?

Thanks

Comment: Why not use version control?

Comment: take a look at Team foundation server, you have a free license also

Comment: github, bitbucket, tfs, svn, etc. Lots of solutions to help you with version control.

Comment: @Sami Kuhmonen Because backup can not be replaced by a source control. Source control is required a manual interaction with a commit/update/merge and so on. A backup system is basically automatic, no need a manual interaction and targeted all/any file on a drive including targets not under source control.

Comment: @Andry Backup should be done *of* the version control system usually, not of project files and rename them to version them. And as you noted they didn’t specify anything automatic, no automated renaming strategy, which hints at manual. Version control systems should be automatically backed up anyway. Also this is a six year old question.

Comment: @Sami Kuhmonen But it's not done, even after a six year old question. And author directly mentioned a backup. If you have a link to such a system then post it, until then all answers around vcs still are incorrect/inaccurate/misleading.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [DPack](http://www.usysware.com/dpack/Default.aspx) extension for Visual Studio includes the Solution Backup tool that creates a zip archive of the solution and auto names it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Manually edit .sln file

This method is entirely aimed at renaming the directory for the project, as viewed in Windows Explorer.

This method does not suffer from the problems in the Remove/add project file method below (references disappearing), but it can result in problems if your project is under source control (see notes below). This is why step 2 (backup) is so important.

1- Close Visual Studio.
2- Create a backup of your .sln file (you can always roll back).
3- Imagine you want to rename directory "Project1" to "Project2".
If not using source control, rename the folder from "Project1" to "Project2" using Windows Explorer.
4- If using source control, rename the folder from "Project1" to "Project2" using the functions supplied by source control. This preserves the history of the file. For example, with TortoiseSVN, right click on the file, select TortoiseSVN .. Rename.
5- In the .sln file, edit all instances of "Project1" to be "Project2", using a text editor like NotePad.
6- Restart Visual Studio, and everything will work as before, but with the project in a different directory.

Alse would recommend TFS, a powerfull tool to do what you pretend. You will be able even to recover previous versions of specific files,if you have any error and you have troubles find it you can see what changes you did since last "check in "  etc. There are many options

Comment: Your top part of the answer is just reinventing a square wheel. Horrible approach IMO.

Comment: honestly, for non professional people who just want to backup a couple projects, this is more convenient. i dont want to invest possibly half an hour into putting extensions or learning git.