# Export Visual Studio Solution

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I want to export the entire solution in visual studio , so i can import that on other computer ?

i searched in the net and didn't find answer to that question , also "you cant to that" is an answer.

i don't want to copy and paste the entire folder , because I have several things on that folder that i don't want to copy them or start delete each file i don't need , i want to export only the things that solution used.

tools or other external apps also will be welcomed

thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30477493/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-make-a-backup-in-visual-studio-2013

Answer (score 1):

Second answer would be to use cloud services or use git with visual studio else sign in and share your files to the location where ever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily export your project files as template to reuse later but not the entire solution.

So press Save All button every time you make changes to your solution projects. Than close the solution file. Go to where they are saved by default and copy entire project solution folder.

Comment: The answer was one of the requirements that the OP didn't want to do.